# How to hide record types in specific apps

Tags: page-layout, record-type, hidden-fields

I am building an HR org. I have 2 different apps within the org- HR org (Applicants are housed in the contacts Object) and Industry Contacts (contacts also housed in the contacts object). I have created 2 different record types, and set up different page layouts for the two apps and info needed. Is there a way to make the HR/ Applicant contact page the default as the only option (auto-launch essentially) when selecting "new" in the HR org, while also only allowing the Industry Contacts record visible and default in the "Industry Contacts" app when selecting new?
Key- I need all users able to view/edit both types of records.